# Accomplishments daemon fails to connect

Tags: accomplishments

My Ubuntu Accomplishment fail to start as the error I got is:

> The daemon fail to connect.

[image]

Please advice.

---

Running `accomplishment-viewer` in the terminal gave me this output:

```
Pidfile /home/r00t/twistd.pid contains non-numeric value
Starting the daemon using command ``twistd -noy /usr/bin/accomplishments-daemon --logfile=/home/r00t/.cache/accomplishments/logs/daemon.log &``
```

This was in the daemon.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1048791/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command to remove the configuration file:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/accomplishments/
```

It is more than likely a problem of an obsolete file and removing the file worked for me when I had the same problem.

After deleting the file, close the application, log out and open it again.

---

Given that the terminal displays `Pidfile /home/r00t/twistd.pid contains non-numeric value`, you can try deleting the `twistd.pid` flie and see if that helps.

```
rm ~/twistd.pid
```

Comment: do i need to reboot after run this command? without reboot the problem is still there... ive logout and login back... but nothing change...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3811/discussion-between-penreturn-and-jokerdino)

Comment: its funny when i click back, its run as usual :) thank for your advice @jokerdino

Comment: delete the twistd.pid at home folder and run back the program solve the issue as u ask me to do that on chat yesterday. :)